# Support Jackson @JsonFilter async DeferredResult

Tags: java, scala, spring-mvc, jackson

base on this [Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12586)

I have this method:

```
val innerResult: DeferredResult[Object] = new DeferredResult[Object]()

override def setResult(result: T): Boolean = {
  val beanPropertyFilter: SimpleBeanPropertyFilter = filter.size match {
    case 0 => SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAll()
    case _ => SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("id")
  }

  val filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider()
                        .addFilter("propertiesFilter", beanPropertyFilter)

  val wrapper = new MappingJacksonValue(result)
  wrapper.setFilters(filterProvider)
  innerResult.setResult(wrapper)
}
```

in the response I see this:

```
{"headers":{}, "body":[{"id":"573080B50CCDED33E08DA678"}], "statusCode":"OK"}
```

while I want to see:

```
[{"id":"573080B50CCDED33E08DA678"}]
```

what I an doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Scala and have trouble following your code (where is `result` defined?). Perhaps add the method declaration and fix the indentation?

In any case, you seem to get the JSON representation of the whole response instead of just the response body. In Java, the `ResponseEntity` class has the following attributes:

- `headers`: the response headers (Cache-Control, etc.)
- `statusCode`: the response status (200 OK, 404 Not Found, etc.)
- `body`: the response body (an array with a single object with an id field in your case)

This part seems fishy:

```
val wrapper = new MappingJacksonValue(result)
innerResult.setResult(wrapper)
```

It looks like you're taking the result (body, header, statusCode) and storing that in the innerResult. Based solely on variable names, this seems backwards.

Comment: it is not matter what the type of result it could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

based on @bernie direction the full code should look like

```
 case class FilterDeferredResult[T <: ResponseEntity[_]](properties: Option[Set[String]] = Some(Set.empty), innerResult: DeferredResult[Object]) extends DeferredResult[T] {
   override def setErrorResult(result: scala.Any): Boolean = {
      super.setErrorResult(result)
   }

  override def setResult(result: T): Boolean = {
      val beanPropertyFilter: SimpleBeanPropertyFilter = properties match {
         case None => SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAll()
         case Some(p) => p.size match {
            case 0 => SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAll()
            case _ => SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(p)
      }
   }

   val filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("propertiesFilter", beanPropertyFilter)
   val wrapper = new MappingJacksonValue(result.getBody)
   wrapper.setFilters(filterProvider)

   val bodyBuilder = new ResponseEntity(wrapper,result.getHeaders, result.getStatusCode)

   innerResult.setResult(bodyBuilder)
  }
}
```

so I need to create new ResponseEntity based on the first one, with the body wrapped in `MappingJacksonValue`